# Nesting Tasks within Tasks trying not to block UI Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, ui-thread

So I have a task which sends a service call... this task has a continuewith so that when the call returns the program can sort out the data. Now I would also like that when the call returns with the data it makes another service call based on that data without blocking the UI thread. Is this possible?

My example code so far is:

```
 Task t = new Task(() =>{//Make my service call};
 t.Start();
 t.ContinueWith((sender) =>
 {
     //sort my data out
     //when thats done make another service call based on that data that doesn't
     // block UI thread
 }, cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: What service are you using? Are the service calls synchronous?

Comment: I'm using WCF and yes they are synchronous. I should also mention I am using .Net 4 and don't really want to rely on the async/await nuget package

Comment: Well then we have a duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889862/using-asynchronous-tasks-to-call-synchronous-wcf-service

Comment: hmm I'm not sure that link answers my question

Comment: Try to use BackgroundWorker then. See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would I use the BackgroundWorker in the ContinueWith i.e. the UI thread?

Comment: Umm.. Create a background worker. Make your servicecall1 in b it's DoWork method. Then do your calculation s in the same. Then in its oncomplete do your servicecall2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants any more info on how to do this:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    Task t = new Task(() =>{//Make my service call};
    t.Start();
    t.ContinueWith((sender) =>
    {
        //sort my data out
        //when thats done make another service call based on that data that doesn't
        // block UI thread

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }, cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     //do some stuff
}
```

This free ebook - [Threading in C# by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) helped alot